# The isomorphism between two $C^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A,B$ be two $C^*$-algebras. If there exist two injective $*$-homomorphisms $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$, can we conclude that $A$ is $*$-isomorphic to $B$?

Comment: For a noncommutative answer, if $\mathbb F_n$ denotes the free group on $n$ generators, one can obtain embeddings $\mathbb F_2\hookrightarrow\mathbb F_3$ and  $\mathbb F_3\hookrightarrow\mathbb F_2$, which extend to embeddings of their reduced $C^*$-algebras: $C^*_r\mathbb F_2\hookrightarrow C^*_r\mathbb F_3$ and $C^*_r\mathbb F_3\hookrightarrow C^*_r\mathbb F_2$. But these two algebras are not isomorphic, because, for instance, their $K_1$-groups differ.

Comment: @Aweygan Thanks，your example is my original question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall that by the [commutative Gelfand-Naimark theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation#The_spectrum_of_a_commutative_C*-algebra), the map $A \mapsto \text{Hom}(A, \mathbb{C})$ establishes a contravariant equivalence of categories between commutative unital $C^{\ast}$-algebras and compact Hausdorff spaces. This equivalence switches monomorphisms and epimorphisms, and with a little work you can show that the monomorphisms of $C^{\ast}$-algebras are precisely the injections and the epimorphisms of compact Hausdorff spaces are precisely the surjections. So, for commutative unital $C^{\ast}$-algebras, your question dualizes to:

> If $X, Y$ are two compact Hausdorff spaces such that there exist continuous surjections $f : X \to Y, g : Y \to X$, then must $X$ and $Y$ be homeomorphic?

The answer is no. For example, take $X = S^1, Y = [-1, 1]$. There is a continuous surjection $X \to Y$ given by, say, the projection to the $x$-axis (thinking of $S^1$ as the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$), and also a continuous surjection $Y \to X$ given by identifying the endpoints, or more explicitly given by $y \mapsto e^{\pi i y}$. But $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic; for example, $Y$ can be disconnected by removing a point but $X$ cannot.

Answer (score 3):

To complement Qiaochu's answer, the double embedding between non-isomorphic C$^*$-algebras is fairly common. Here are some examples.

- C$^{*\vphantom{j}}_r(\mathbb F_n)$, reduced C$^*$-algebras of free groups (this was mentioned by Aweygan in the comments). It was proven by Pimsner-Voiculescu that they are non-isomorphic, and the mutual embedding comes from the usual mutual group embedding between $\mathbb F_n$ and $\mathbb F_m$.
- Cuntz algebras $\mathcal O_n$. There is maybe a more ad-hoc argument, but it follows from Kirchberg-Phillips result that all exact C$^*$-algebras embed in $\mathcal O_2$ (and thus $\mathcal O_n$). The Cuntz algebras are nuclear and hence exact.
- In the non-separable case we can look at von Neumann algebras, and examples are also kind of common there, too. Looking at separable (in the von Neumann sense) factors, every type II$_\infty$ and type III factor contains a copy of $B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$ (this, because II$_\infty$ factors are of the form $M\otimes B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$ with $M$ of type II$_1$, and type III factors always satisfy $M\simeq M\otimes B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$). So for any two properly infinite separable von Neumann factors $M_1$ and $M_2$ we have a mutual embedding.

Comment: This question is now unfortunately in the deletion list (D1) of the CURED chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61828891#61828891

Comment: Yes, the amount of questions with good answers these people have deleted is astonishing.

Comment: Can the math community do something about that?

Comment: Unlikely. These people spend significant time doing this and they do have some support. The majority wants to come to the site to talk about math, and not to fight over deletions. Years ago there was a counter-chatroom to CRUDE, but it never got enough traction.